# This condition will always return 'false' since the types '1' and '2' have no overlap

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to show/hide div based on returned variable number, status variable always returns 1 or 2. but i get error in my html:

This condition will always return 'false' since the types '1' and '2' have no overlap.

what am i doing wrong?

.ts

```
status: number;

   this.service.GetEstimationId(params['id']).subscribe(response => {
     this.status = response.estimationStatus;
     console.log(typeof this.status); // returns number
    });
```

.html

```
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end" *ngIf="status === 1">
    <button (click)="toggleEdit(null, true)" type="submit" class="btn-green mt-3 send">
      <i class="far fa-file-alt mr-2"></i> Send
    </button>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end" *ngIf="status === 2">
      <button (click)="toggleEdit(null, false)" type="submit" class="btn-green mt-3 send">
        <i class="far fa-file-alt mr-2"></i> Save
      </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you checked the type of `response.estimationStatus` ? Is this a string ("1" or a number 1) ?

Comment: Hi, it is a number for sure.

Comment: i cosole.logged typeof and it returns number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `===` for checking the condition which is used for comparing two variables and also checks datatype.

You can change the type to number:

`this.status = Number(response.estimationStatus)`

**or**
use `==` instead.

`*ngIf="status == 1"`

Also seems that you forgot to close the first `div` tag:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end" *ngIf="status === 1">
  <button type="submit" class="btn-green mt-3 send">
    <i class="far fa-file-alt mr-2"></i> Send
  </button>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end" *ngIf="status === 2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-green mt-3 send">
      <i class="far fa-file-alt mr-2"></i> Save
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer but i have same error. i created simple stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkyjny?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I think You forgot to close first `<div>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It wasn't the problem. The real problem was in nesting two divs inside each other. I've posted my new answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71495025/13523914

---

my old answer:

Seems like status is a string. I mean, you think it as 1 or 2 but it's actually "1" or "2". So there's two ways to solve it.

1. The best approach is to turn them to numbers. use `Number(status) === 1`
2. You can forget type checking and let the type coercion happen. It's not best practice. `status == 1`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. it is number for sure, i console logged typeof so it returns number.

Comment: I tried your code but i have still have same error.

Comment: i created simple stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkyjny?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @aelin_galathius okay, I checked your file. Now I realise the problem is you put the divs in a nested way! so the error happens for the second div, mentioning that status can't be 1 and 2 in the same time.

Comment: @aelin_galathius check it
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6adwaw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I've made this a new answer now

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that your two divs are nested, and the status can't be 1 and 2 at the same time.
put the second div outside the first, and it will be solved.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end" *ngIf="status===1">
  <button type="submit" class="btn-green mt-3 send">
    <i class="far fa-file-alt mr-2"></i> Send
  </button>
</div>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-end" *ngIf="status===2">
  <button type="submit" class="btn-green mt-3 send">
    <i class="far fa-file-alt mr-2"></i> Save
  </button>
</div>
```